# In DjangoCMS Can I have an HTMLField which has use of the cmsplugins?

Tags: django-cms

I'm buidling a site with DjangoCMS 3.1, using a mix of traditional Django Models with fields and DjangoCMS placeholders. This is fine in principal, but it doesn't really allow for a clean workflow for the site administrators as they have to edit half of a model in the more traditional admin interface, and then the placeholder via the front-end editor interface. As I don't really need the full front-end-editing interface to simplify things such I wanted to convert all of the fields defined as PlaceHolderField's into HTMLFields.

Having done this I am having problems accessing the CMSplugins from within CKEditor in the admin interface; the appropriate button shows up in CKEditor, but the drop down menu is empty:

[image]

This is my (simplified) model description:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField('Start Date', blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField('End Date', blank=True, null=True)
    subtitle =  models.CharField('Sub Title', max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    contents = HTMLField('Contents')
```

Admin declaration:

```
class ProjectAdmin(FrontendEditableAdminMixin, reversion.VersionAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,
            {'fields':
                [
                    'title',
                    'type',
                    'start_date',
                    'end_date',
                    'subtitle',
                    'summary',
                    'contents',
                ]
            }
        ),
        ('Meta Information',{
                'classes': ('collapse',),
                'fields':
                [
                    'slug',
                    'legacy_id',
                    'created_date',
                    'modified_date',
                ],
            }
        )
    ]

    frontend_editable_fields = (
        'title',
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
        'lead_image',
        'subtitle',
        'summary',
        'contents'
    )
```

Settings.py

```
CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {
    'language': '{{ language }}',
    'toolbar_HTMLField':  [
        ['Undo', 'Redo'],
        ['cmsplugins', '-', 'ShowBlocks'],
        ['Format', 'Styles'],
        ['TextColor', 'BGColor', '-', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord'],
        ['Maximize', ''],
        '/',
        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'],
        ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote', '-', 'Table'],
        ['Source']
    ],
    'skin': 'moono',
}
```

I've tried declaring CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF inside of settings.py just in case:

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'contents': {
        'name' : 'Contents',
        'plugins': ['TextPlugin', 'PicturePlugin', 'VideoPlugin', 'LinkPlugin'],
        'text_only_plugins': ['LinkPlugin'],
        'default_plugins':[
            {
                'plugin_type':'TextPlugin',
                'values':{
                    'body':'<p></p>'
                },
            },
        ],
         'child_classes': {
            'TextPlugin': ['PicturePlugin', 'VideoPlugin', 'LinkPlugin'],
        },
        'parent_classes': {
            'LinkPlugin': ['TextPlugin'],
        },
    }
}
```

Looking at the source that shouldn't affect it, only the definition of PlaceHolderFields. I've tried adding the PlaceholderAdminMixin to the admin class declaration as well.

I'm accessing the admin interface via modal dialogs launched via `{% render_model project 'contents' %}` so to some extent it is within the DjangoCMS context, but it's not using the full front end interface.

Is this even possible? That is can I access the DjangoCMS Plugins via CKEditor in the Django Admin interface, without reverting to using the PlaceholderField/ full Front end editing interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The supported way to do this is to use `PlaceholderField` (where you're trying to use `HTMLField`.

See http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/how_to/placeholders.html for more information.

Comment: I've been using PlaceHolderfield, but as I say in my question that makes the administrator workflow cumbersome; a user has to create an instance of the model, fill in the fields in the admin interface, then switch to 'structure' create a textfield in the placeholder, then edit the contents there. For the relatively simple content in the field I don't need the extra overhead of the PlaceHolderField functionality and the extra usability issues.

Comment: In particular see here: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/how_to/placeholders.html#admin-integration : " any PlaceholderFields in it will only be available for editing from the frontend."

Comment: Yes, but you need a placeholder to add plugins, that's why I wrote "the supported way".

Edit: anyway, the solution would be to make your model completely editable in the frontend, see http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/how_to/toolbar.html

Comment: thanks @ojii, you've made me realise my mistake - I'd thought of the cmsplugins inserting HTML elements into the HTML field, not the subsequent abstraction at the model/database level that the placeholderfield makes. I'll revert this branch and try and work out a good workflow for the site adminstrators.